# using operators with zipWithN

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Say, we can write something like this:

```
zipWith (,) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
```

If we want to tuple 3 list, we can write:
    zipWith3 (,,) [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9]

We can also use  `zipWith4 (,,,) zipWith5(,,,,)` and so on.

Now, I want to do the same thing, but using adding instead comma operator. 
Is there any way to define it in the same terse way, not using lambdas like in

```
zipWith3 (\a b c -> a + b + c) [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]
```

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: This is not the main point of the question and you may know this, but `zipWith (,)` is `zip`, `zipWith3 (,,)` is `zip3`, and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you want "point free" style code for `\a b c -> a + b + c`.  Let it be known that, in general, `\a b c -> a + b + c` is often preferable to point free code because it is much easier to read four weeks later when you found a bug.

There is a wiki article on point free programming ([source](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree)).

You can also install the `pointfree` package, which lets you solve these problems on the command line.  For example,

```
$ pointfree '\x y z -> x + y + z'
((+) .) . (+)
```

So `((+) .) . (+)` is the point free version (x, y, and z are the "points", in case you were wondering, and no, this has nothing to do with geometry).  You can use that definition if you'd like, but most people will look at your code and will have no idea what that funny looking piece of ASCII art is supposed to do.  Half of them will work it out with pencil and paper, but isn't the original `\x y z -> x + y + z` so much easier on the eyes?

Hint: If you ever need to figure out what some point free code does, look at the type:

```
Prelude> :t ((+) .) . (+)
((+) .) . (+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
```

Or you can install the `pointful` package, which is approximately the inverse of `pointfree`.

**Summary:** Welcome to the world of points free programming, proceed with caution lest your code be unreadable.

Comment: Dietrich, thank you for this answer. It was always a puzzle to me this style of programming called pointfree, since actually we often use a lot of point in pointfree code ) yes, I know about ((+) .).(+) but I can not call it more terse version )

Comment: Why is `((+) .) . (+)` not a more terse version?

Comment: @Dietrich If what you want to do was more common there would be a more terse way of doing it.

Comment: @Dietrich - of course, it depends on what we exactly mean by "terse". by "terse" i mean balance of mainly two things - 1. length 2. readability and intuitiveness.  actually is is not much shorter and as for intuitiveness, well, when one sees (,,) or a + b +c i believe he will guess what it does exactly means more probably than if he sees this boobiefull-style construction )

Comment: Or of course, `add3`, and then put it in a `where`: "...`where add3 a b c = a + b + c`"

Answer (score 7):

Another option: applicative functors. In fact, Control.Applicative contains newtype definition [ZipList](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors#ZipLists) (since there are several possible definitions of Applicative for list type) which can be used like that:

```
import Control.Applicative 

getZipList $ (,,) <$> ZipList [1,2,3] <*> ZipList [4,5,6] <*> ZipList [7,8,9]
```

or like that (for a couple of (+)'s):

```
getZipList $ (+) <$> ((+) <$> ZipList [1,2,3] <*> ZipList [4,5,6]) <*> ZipList [7,8,9]
```

Even though it probably doesn't make much sense to use applicative functors for this particular problem, they nevertheless provide very powerful abstraction/mechanism for solving similar kind of tasks, so they are definitely worth learning (e.g. we can get rid of zipWith3, zipWith4 ... etc).

Comment: Sometimes I wish ZipList were the default applicative instance for lists because it's so handy.  Of course there's a good reason why it isn't, but it would still be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Bypassing zipWith3, you can do:

```
import Data.List (transpose)
map sum $ transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

While using zipWith3 cuts the output to shortest list, this doesn't, i.e. for [[1,2],[3]] it gives [4,2].

Comment: as I've already said to MarcoS, by changing input's data structure we can use lot of different approaches - for example,  sum $ map sum [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

Comment: @shabunc: This code computes exactly the same thing as zipWith3 (\a b c -> a+b+c) ..., differs only when lists are different lengths. sum $ map sum [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] computes sum (1+2+3)+(4+5+6)+(7+8+9) while sum $ map sum $ transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] computes sum (1+4+7)+(2+5+8)+(3+6+9).

Comment: exactly, but the input data's structures in both cases differs from that about this question is. If we have anything like  [[a]] of course we can use all the spectrum of list manipulating functions.

Comment: @shabunc: Ah, you mean that my solution takes a list of lists, while originally you take three lists. I agree, this is different. I don't know any better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot write it without lamda. In fact `zipWith3` requires as first parameter a function that takes 3 parameters, and `(+)` takes only two. So, you need to define "a plus function taking 3 parameters", that is exactly what your lambda does.

An alternative is:

```
foldr1 (zipWith (+)) [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
```

I don't know if the above is terser than

```
zipWith3 (\a b c -> a + b + c) [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: nope. this way we are changing input data's structure. if we have  [[a]] than we can easily do something like sum $ concat [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

Comment: @shabunc: warning: `sum $ concat [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` is not the same as `foldr1 (zipWith (+)) [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]`